# Line 19: Char 1: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] } ^ 1 error generated

Tags: runtime

```
int solvetab(int d,int f,int t){
  vector<vector<int>>dp(d+1,vector<int>(t+1,0));
  dp[0][0]=1;
  for(int dice=1;dice<=d;dice++){
    for(int target=1;target<=t;target++){
       int ans=0;
          for(int i=1;i<=f;i++){
            ans=ans+dp[dice-1][target-i];
          }
          dp[dice][target]=ans;
    }
  }
  return dp[d][f];
}
```

try to solve but get earro
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000030 overflowed to 0x60200000002c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34